# Write sql query as PDO statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

while updating some of my SQL queries I ran into one which I have no clue how to translate to a PDO statement.

```
$header = $db_handle->runQuery("
        SELECT event_name,location,subject,details, $user_table.user_login AS Received_From,event_start_time,event_end_time,
            CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 'Accepted'
                  WHEN status = '2' THEN 'Cancelled'
                  ELSE 'Pending' END as status,datetime AS Invite_Date,meeting_date
            FROM $event_table
        WHERE user_id = $user_ID
");
```

my main issue is with the `AS` and `CASE WHEN THEN` statements.

What I have so far:

```
$stmt = $dbHandle->prepare(
            "
            SELECT event_name, subject, details, location, meeting_date, event_start_time, event_end_time
            FROM wp_request_event
            WHERE sender_id = ?
            ");
    $stmt->execute([$user_ID]);
    $header = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Anyone any help or pointers?

Comment: Identifiers like table / column names should be whitelisted instead as they cannot be bound. You can only bind the `$userID`.

Comment: Option 1. retrieve the status as-is and translate the value in your view layer to a description.

Comment: Option 2: change the status column to an enum, then proceed with option 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AS` and `CASE WHEN THEN` statements are totally irrelevant to PDO. You can keep them with your PDO statement as well.

the only issue, as it was pointed out in the comments, is a table name, which I hope you can put in the query as is, without storing it in a variable

Comment: He can still save the table in a variable. Just concat it as in default SQL.